# Identity for any iOS block

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In iOS, we can use void*, id or NSObject* to represent any object instance.

Is there a way to represent any ios block?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of block? are you asking for ^ one??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocks are Objective-C objects, so `id` can be used.

```
    void(^block)(void) = ^{ NSLog(@"Hello, world!"); };
    id foo = block;
```

Comment: How can I make a call to it ? suppose id foo = void(^block)(int).  Should I   (void(^block)(int)foo)(2);   or I can  foo(2) or [foo 2]; thanks

Comment: You currently need to cast back to a block pointer before you call.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's reference: "You can cast a block reference to a pointer of arbitrary type and vice versa." so you can cast a block to type `id` as well.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW1